# Getting pixel nearest neighbor color

Tags: python, numpy

I have an image with edges looks like this:

[image]

And I'm using this two methods to fix the edges:

```
def get_colors(pil_image, limit=4):
    pil_image = np.array(pil_image)
    image_colors = {}
    for row in pil_image:
        for pxl in row:
            pxl = tuple(pxl)
            if not image_colors.get(pxl):
                image_colors[pxl] = 1
            else:
                image_colors[pxl] += 1
    sorted_image_colors = sorted(image_colors, key=image_colors.get, reverse=True)
    return sorted_image_colors[:limit]


def remove_anti_aliasing(colors, img_ndarr):
    colors = np.array(colors).astype(np.int32)
    img_ndarr = img_ndarr.astype(np.int32)
    distances = np.argmin(np.array([np.sqrt(np.sum((color - img_ndarr) ** 2, axis=2)) for color in colors]), axis=0)
    return colors[distances].astype(np.uint8)
```

And the result looks like this:

[image]

The edges still looks like the first but now the color is limited to 4.

I want to achieve something like this where there's only 2 colors on the edges:

[image]

How can I do that?